# Isospin and Hypercharge of the SU(2) bps monopole embedding

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, topological-field-theory, representation-theory

I am reading the paper [Fundamental monopoles and multimonopole solutions for arbitrary simple gauge groups - Weinberg, Erick J](http://cds.cern.ch/record/133713/files/) .

In appendix C of this paper the author states, that the solution obtained (eqn 2.20) by embedding a SU(2) bps monopole, in a gauge theory of higher rank, can be categorized by a **natural isospin $t$, and a hypercharge $y$**. What is ispospin and hypercharge in this context?

I explain more about the solution. For each simple root $\beta^{(a)}$ of an arbitrary gauge group, you can define a SU(2) subgroup with generators, $t_1, t_2, t_3$ given in **eqn 2.20,** and a set of scalar and gauge fields, that satisfy the bps monopole equations of unit charge.

HE says the generators belonging to the cartan sub algebra H are isospin singlets with $y=0$. What does this mean? And also for other roots, $t_3$ and $y$ are given by **(eqn C.1)**

$$t_3 E_{\alpha}=[t_3, E_{\alpha}]=[\frac{\beta \cdot H}{\beta^2},E_{\alpha}]=\frac{\beta \cdot \alpha}{\beta^2}E_{\alpha}$$
$$yE_{\alpha}=(\frac{h \cdot \alpha}{h \cdot \beta}-t_3)E_{\alpha}$$

Here, $\beta$ is any root of the gauge group, $E_{\alpha}$ is the raising operator, and $h$ is the vector formed by the components of the scalar field $\phi$ along generators of $H$.